# "MRTK" missing from project settings tab

Tags: unity-game-engine, mrtk

Following intro to MRTK tutorial(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/learn-mrtk-tutorials/1-5-exercise-configure-resources), upon checking 'Project settings' I am unable to see any 'MRTK' option even though it has been installed already(all steps in tutorial are followed correctly up till now).

Tried making another project, different Unity version, but no luck.

[my 'project settings'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ud6pd.png)